# I do not understand partials

Tags: hugo

My wordpress site was hacked three weeks ago and I switched to hugo. My website is almost done, except for two details: Google Analytics and share buttons.

I searched the internet for the answers to my problems. However, I cannot make them work. Take the share buttons for instance. I found [this tutorial](https://gohugohq.com/partials/add-this-social-sharing/) that says that I need to put two files (`addthis.html` and `addthis-script.html`) in layouts/partials. I put these two files there. I edited my `config.toml` file with my Add-This details as well.

But I cannot make these share buttons appear in my blog posts! I edited `layouts/_default/single.html` with

```
{{ partial "addthis" . }} 
{{ partial "addthis-script" . }}
```

right before

```
{{- partial "tags.html" . -}}
```

and nothing happens. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot figure out what is.

The same goes for Google Analytics. I have no idea where I can put the partial to make it register my site visitors.

If it is important, I am using [ananke theme](https://github.com/budparr/gohugo-theme-ananke/).

Comment: At the very least it looks like you need to add the “.html” extension to you filenames.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are other partial in that same directory working?  Perhaps there's additional configuration that needs to get done?  I don't know Hugo, so I can't really say for sure. :-(